# What's the difference between open Subtitles and open captions in Premiere Pro CC 2018?

Tags: premiere, subtitles

The only difference I've spotted is that you can edit the font in open captions but not in open subtitles. But i'm sure there's another point to it.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found out that the difference is in the export options of this type of caption, aside from in editing the subtitles. You can export open subtitles as a sidecar file with the same formats you get in teletext, while you can only burn open captions into video.

Comment: Untrue. You can export open captions: Go to Export > Caption. You can choose between STL and XML.

Answer (score 1):

This bothered me too. From what I see, "Open subtitling" is a special EBU standard, and is subject to the restrictions of captioning spec (probably Teletext, but I'm no PAL expert). Therefore there's no raster resolution, no fonts, colors etc., just a "grid size" for the number of (unformatted) characters.

Open captions are intended to be burned into the video, but offer the handy benefit of import and export.

Looks like both types can export to STL and XML. But "Open subtitling" can also export to EBU N19 format.